# Debugger is not working on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual studio 2022 with .NET Framework 6.0 while i am trying to debug application not hit the breakpoint at the starting point. try to apply debugger on program.cs class

I have applied all these changes but still not working for me .I don't know what happen.

1. TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General, disable "Require source
   files to exactly match the original version" .
2. TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols, enable the Microsoft Symbols
   Server.
3. TOOLS->Options->Debugging, check "Enable Just My Code'
   and "use Manage/Unmanage mode".

Also to many times restart the system and update the visual studio .

Please suggest the solution .

Comment: Try -> Clean Solution/Rebuild Solution, if it fails exit Visual Studio and remove the hidden folder _.vs_, if it fails reset the whole settings using the menu Import/Export Settings or _devenv /ResetSettings_

Comment: Make sure you are not building with the `Release` configuration.

Comment: _"with .NET Framework 6.0", it's just .NET 6. .NET Framework finished at 4.8.1. Then there was .NET Core and then just .NET (which is the same and just dropped "Core" from version 5 onwards).

Comment: If the breakpoint is too early in the code, it may be too early for the debugger to be attached successfully before the breakpoint is hit. Can you show us the code where you have the breakpoint?

Comment: @phuzi I think that if this is true then we will never be able to start the app with just F10 and start the debug from the very first line of code.

Comment: @steve I have F10 mapped to `Debug.StepOver` what do you have F10 mapped to?

Comment: @phuzi you are correct. With F10 or F11 it doesn't stop. I was certain that this was the expected behavior but... however setting the breakpoint on the first line in main doesn't seem to be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable the "Enable JavaScript debugging....." from TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Genera window.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

That happens to me ~ once per week. To resolve it, I can shut down Visual Studio and delete the hidden `.vs` folder. After that it's fine again.

Microsoft is probably debugging this already, except they can't, because their breakpoints are not working.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint in Javascript code and enable the Javascript debugger?

Comment: @Steve: sorry, I don't do web development, just .NET (C#) development.

Comment: I was hopeful this would work but it did not. But I believe it has something to do with enabling JavaScript debugger.  I'll never enable it again.   Have tried everything short of reinstalling Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Experienced a very similar problem just two days ago. No matter what I do, when I put a single breakpoint on my project and then start a debug session, the Visual Studio stop to respond without any clear reason.

Some time the app starts and shows the home screen but the browser doesn't stop spinning and the whole app doesn't respond to any mouse or keyboard interaction.

Some time the app starts normally but then, when I reach the breakpoint code, the app stops responding again and shows just a white page.

Of course I have tried the usual workarounds when something inexplicable happens with Visual Studio.

- First I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution. No change
- Second I have manually deleted the obj and bin folder. (just
  because). No change
- Third I have exited Visual Studio and manually removed the hidden .vs
  folder. So goodbye to breakpoints and open tabs, but this also fails
  at the first newly set breakpoint
- Finally, I took the last hammer short of reinstalling, and ran to the
  Tools Menu, selected the Import/Export Settings and choose the Clear
  All Settings. (I have saved the current settings to compare them with old settings but there are too many difference to tell what's really important or not).

This has resolved the problem (so far) and I can now apply my breakpoints as expected. Of course this means that more configurations are lost like External Tools, Color Schemes etc... so, if you reach this point, be ready to reinstall a bunch of things.

**UPDATE**
Stopped working again but this time I have found the culprit.
It is the Javascript Debugger enabled. When you put a breakpoint on js code anywhere in your project the VS ide asks you to enable the debugger and that's the change that bring back the problem.
Disable the JS debugger and you have again a (semi)functional debug environment. Of course this is not a solution. MS says that this is a problem caused by version 111 of the Chromium engine and [a fix is in development](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/When-Debugging-Browser-does-not-finish/10311194#T-ND10312833)

**UPDATE BIS**
It seems they have fixed it. If you have Edge Dev installed, this morning a new version has been deployed. Version 112.0.1722.15. After updating it, **Edge 111.0.1661.51 (Official Builder)** and **Chrome 111.0.5563.110 (Official build)** started to work again.