# Application .NET c# VisualStudio DEBUG MODE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've got some problem with a C# .NET application.
Then I tried to run VS 2022 (v 17.5.2 ) in DEBUG MODE without a breakpoint and it works. But when I add a breakpoint (it doesn't matter where) the application doesn't start.

Chrome starts but still refreshing the page ( page is blank ). When I run the .NET APP in standard option - I see new changes and everything is working.

I always run APP in IIS MODE on localhost (http://localhost:6257/) - probably with ISS Express.

Any ideas ? I've remove all breakpoints from project, restart PC, redownload project from GIT.

Comment: This virus is striking many programmers without an obvious solution beyond removing all breakpoints.  VS2022 is currently too broken to be usable.  Stay below version 17.4.0, perhaps by using the "rollback update" installer feature.

Comment: See my answer to the same problem today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765170/debugger-is-not-working-on-visual-studio-2022/75766454#75766454 three similar problems in the last days start to appear to be some kind of bug

Comment: First of all, please update VS to the latest version. Then in Visual Studio, there is a drop-down bar on the left side of running your project => Debug Properties => IIS Express => IIS Express digits => choose x86 or x64 according to your own situation. If it doesn't work you can delete the .vs (hidden folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first step try to enable `native code debugging` option in the app properties:

`Properties -> Debug -> General -> Open debug launch profiles UI`

Another try would be to delete solution.suo file

> - close solution
> - remove solution.suo file
> - reopen solution

These and the rest options are listed in this topic:
[Debugging doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374530/debugging-doesnt-start)