# VisualStudio Debug not working on Edge and Chrome. Any clue?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2022

I'm using VisualStudio (2022) for many time for web development being able to debug correctly in VS IDE. This week, when I run my site with debug enabled both Edge and Chrome cannot open any files (they seem to crash, keep trying to open any files without success, like waiting for internet response). When I turn off «Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET» I am able to open the webpages but without debug anymore.

I believe it is not an IIS issue since I can run directly localhost (without debug on VS)

Any clue for a troubleshoot?
Tryied to clean+recompile without success

Thanks

Comment: This is starting to happen too frequently to be some kind of hiccup of some machine. Yours is the fourth question I see in the last days about strange behavior of debug in Visual Studio. FWIW take a look at [my answer at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765170/debugger-is-not-working-on-visual-studio-2022/75766454#75766454) So far the final step there still works.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I've made a full repair on VS2022 setup and it solved the problem.

Comment: That problem is on its way to be fixed. Please [check this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765170/debugger-is-not-working-on-visual-studio-2022/75766454#75766454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Steve comment, I've made a full repair on VS setup and it solved the problem.